# python camelot csv format output doesn't work

Tags: python-camelot

I'm trying to extract data from pdf to excel. I use below camelot command to get csv file. But didn't generate csv file. Otherwise, output file didn't created in provided path.

`camelot -p 5 -f csv -o "C:\Users\loginName\Downloads\01.06.2023\Convert" lattice C:\Users\loginName\Downloads\01.06.2023\02062023094633.PDF`

[image: camelot output]

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because forget to add file in output.